# Convert numerical amount to words in vb.net showing Type Expected error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to convert numeric numbers to words in vb.net. But somewhere I am getting Type Expected error. Below is my entire code. I am also putting code separately where this error is coming.

```
Public Shared Function ConvertNumbertoWords(number As Integer) As String
    If number = 0 Then
        Return "ZERO"
    End If
    If number < 0 Then
        Return Convert.ToString("minus ") & ConvertNumbertoWords(Math.Abs(number))
    End If
    Dim words As String = ""
    If (number / 1000000) > 0 Then
        words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000000) & Convert.ToString(" MILLION ")
        number = number Mod 1000000
    End If
    If (number / 1000) > 0 Then
        words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 1000) & Convert.ToString(" THOUSAND ")
        number = number Mod 1000
    End If
    If (number / 100) > 0 Then
        words += ConvertNumbertoWords(number / 100) & Convert.ToString(" HUNDRED ")
        number = number Mod 100
    End If
    If number > 0 Then
        If words <> "" Then
            words += "AND "
        End If
        Dim unitsMap = New () {"ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE",
            "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN",
            "TWELVE", "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN",
            "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN"}
        Dim tensMap = New () {"ZERO", "TEN", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FORTY", "FIFTY",
            "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY"}

        If number < 20 Then
            words += unitsMap(number)
        Else
            words += tensMap(number / 10)
            If (number Mod 10) > 0 Then
                words += " " + unitsMap(number Mod 10)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return words
End Function
```

In below line I am getting Type Expected error

```
Dim unitsMap = New () {"ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE",
                "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN",
                "TWELVE", "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN",
                "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN"}
            Dim tensMap = New () {"ZERO", "TEN", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FORTY", "FIFTY",
                "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY"}
```

Comment: Why don't you write it as a loop, working from the right to the left.  All you have to do is remember that the American counting system actually confuses the denary number system by introducing number names in the wrong places, for instance, 1,000,000,000 is not truly one billion, it's a thousand million. Bearing this in mind, it should be easy enough for you to write a recursive function to work out each of the sections using two or three arrays. Your version above is seriously flawed as it only goes up to 1,000,000, and you're missing 100,000 out of your `If` checks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are not specifying the type of array you are about to declare.i got no error when i tried with this

```
  Dim unitsMap  = New string() {"ZERO", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "ELEVEN", "TWELVE", "THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN","EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN"}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution worked but can you check my code is correct or not because I have set numerical value 3256 but Got this output (ZERO MILLION ZERO MILLION ZERO THOUSAND ZERO HUNDRED AND THREE THOUSAND ZERO MILLION ZERO THOUSAND ZERO HUNDRED AND THREE HUNDRED AND SIXTY SIX)

Comment: unfortunately your code doesnt seem to work fine.please have a look in this link,i think it will help you.

Comment: Which link? Please check

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/538816/Convert-Numbers-to-Words-Neatly

Answer (score 0):

Even though number is an integer, number / 1000000 returns a double with the value .003256 (when number is 3256), which is > 0

For integer division, use \

```
If (number \ 1000000) > 0 Then
```

[floating-point division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/floating-point-division-operator)

[integer division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator)

Note: number is the name if the variable in the OP. “The” number is not better formatting.